# Vb.Net load crystal report in a thread

Tags: multithreading, performance, crystal-reports, report

I am using VS2010 to develop my application. I am trying to solve the problem of loading the crystal report for the first time. I know I should use a thread to load a dummy report but I have failed to code that.

I have created a dummy report called rptDummy.rpt which has nothing to display, but just to initiate the dll files for the crystal report engine to load and make other reports faster to load from the first time.

Here is the following code I use in main form to load this dummy report:

```
Dim trd As Thread
trd = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadTask)
trd.IsBackground = True
trd.Start()
```

And the function is:

```
Private Sub ThreadTask()
    Try
        repDoc = New rptDummy
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
    Thread.Sleep(100)
End Sub
```

But this does not seems to solve the problem! It still take long time to load.
What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Try loading the actual report that's taking a long time instead of a dummy.